# How do I change values to numeric in r?

Tags: r

**Reproducible Sample Data**

```r
df <- data.frame(
  change_time = c("[4605]", "[4000]", "[4305]", 
                  "[5530]", "[6500]", "[5653]", 
                  "[2936]", "[4691]", "[2500]")
)
```

[data frame with values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0Oe7.png)

Hi,
how do I change values to numeric?
so far I've used as.numeric(), but I get the warning
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: `x <- c("[4605]", "[4000]");as.numeric(gsub("\\[|\\]", "", x))`. Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the code you've tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `dplyr` and `stringr` packages. `mutate` allows you to modify the existing `change_time` variable. `str_remove_all` is used to remove the matches pattern in the `change_time` variable. `as.numeric` converts the `change_time` variable from `character` to `numeric`.

Replace `df` with the name of your dataset.

```r
# Recreate sample data 

df <- data.frame(
  change_time = c("[4605]", "[4000]", "[4305]", "[5530]", "[6500]", "[5653]", "[2936]", "[4691]", "[2500]")
)

# Import the libraries

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# Code to accomplish what is asked

df %>% 
  mutate(
    change_time = as.numeric(str_remove_all(change_time, "\\[|\\]"))
    )

# Output

#>   change_time
#> 1        4605
#> 2        4000
#> 3        4305
#> 4        5530
#> 5        6500
#> 6        5653
#> 7        2936
#> 8        4691
#> 9        2500
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You're welcome and welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer suites your needs, please consider marking it accepted by clicking the checkmark and or upvoting as well.

Answer (score 0):

when dealing with R object, it is wise to use str() function to see what data types your are having. I'm not sure, but I'm assume that your data is a stringwith [ ] in each side.

```
 #Install from tidyverse or manually
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)
str_extract(df$change_time,"\\d*") %>% as.numeric()
```